# Can I add custom logic to a Bot Framework PromptDialog for handling invalid answers?

Tags: c#, botframework

In my Bot Framework project, I'm using a PromptDialog to show a predefined set of valid options, with the below code:

```cs
        var pickListOptions = new List<Option>();
        pickListOptions.AddRange(
            _currentQuestion.validValues.Select(x => Option.CreateOption(x)));

        PromptDialog.Choice(context, choiceSelected,
            pickListOptions,
            _currentQuestion.label,
             "Sorry, I didn't get that", 3, PromptStyle.Keyboard);
```

When a free-form answer is typed in which is not in the list of valid values is entered, the "Sorry, I didn't get that" message is automatically displayed and the question is reprompted. However, I want to potentially handle certain invalid answers with a different dialog (i.e. if the user is asking for help). Is there any way to override the automatic reprompt with custom logic?

Answer (score 4):

There are likely two valid answers for this question:

1. If you want to change the validation, you can inherit from the `PromptChoice` and override the `TryParse` or the `MessageReceivedAsync` methods. For example, the [CancelablePromptChoice](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers/ContosoFlowers.BotAssets/Dialogs/CancelablePromptChoice.cs)
2. For handling global commands, like help, instead of doing what I explained in #1, you might want to consider using `Scorables`. Take a look to the [GlobalMessagesHandlers](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-GlobalMessageHandlers) sample to understand more.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, for help, Scorables probably makes sense, but I've got what's likely an impractically wide range of questions a user may ask - essentially, I want to fire off another flow for any non-expected answer. I'm looking at inheriting/overriding now - hopefully this works out!

Comment: Awesome. Please mark as answered if the inheriting glow works for you.