# How to pass user text directly to LUIS at Prompt choice for which the is option does not exist

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have been working on the Bot Framework, in that i have created the Prompt choice as Yes, No, I'm independent type of question. But if i enter the any text which was not present the option List then i should pass the user text to LUIS for hitting the corresponding Intent. I have tried that by getting the user text in Catch block but (await result) not getting the user text.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vReVG.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I add custom logic to a Bot Framework PromptDialog for handling invalid answers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44704544/can-i-add-custom-logic-to-a-bot-framework-promptdialog-for-handling-invalid-answ)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following prompt:

```
PromptDialog.Choice(context, this.ChoiceReceivedAsync, new List<string>() { "Choice 1", "Choice 2" }, "stuff and things");
```

in the resume after method, you can apply logic on the users choice like:

```
    private Task ChoiceReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
    {
       Activity a = context.Activity as Activity;
        switch (a.Text)
        {
            case "Choice 1":
                //do stuff
                break;
            case "Choice 2":
                //do stuff
                break;
            default:
                context.Forward(new Luis(), afterLuis, context.Activity, CancellationToken.None);
                break;
        }

        a = a.CreateReply("things");
        context.PostAsync(a);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

That way if the user enters anything other than a choice it will be sent to `Luis()`  which in my case is a `public class Luis : LuisDialog<object>` or a Luis dialog to handle Luis calls.

You could also have done it like this calling the LUIS API rather than using a LUIS dialog.

```
    private async Task ChoiceReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
    {
       Activity a = context.Activity as Activity;
        switch (a.Text)
        {
            case "Choice 1":
                //do stuff
                break;
            case "Choice 2":
                //do stuff
                break;
            default:
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    string RequestURI = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/YOUR_MODEL_ID?" +
                                        "subscription-key=YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY&amp;verbose=true&amp;timezoneOffset=0&amp;q=" +
                                        a.Text;

                    HttpResponseMessage msg = await client.GetAsync(RequestURI);
                    if (msg.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var JsonDataResponse = await msg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        LUISData luisData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LUISData>(JsonDataResponse);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        a = a.CreateReply("things");
        await context.PostAsync(a);
    }
```

in order to do it this way you would have to add classes like this to support the deserialization.

```
    public class LUISData
    {
        public string query { get; set; }
        public LUISIntent[] intents { get; set; }
        public LUISEntity[] entities { get; set; }
    }
    public class LUISEntity
    {
        public string Entity { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string StartIndex { get; set; }
        public string EndIndex { get; set; }
        public float Score { get; set; }
    }
    public class LUISIntent
    {
        public string Intent { get; set; }
        public float Score { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Once the user enter any other values it should get the text and send to LUIS for processing then after that it should hit the corresponding Intent(LUIS decided intent according to the top scoring intent) its similar to user entering the text....