# How to change [Prompt.Choice] options' color? C# botframework SDK3

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot

How to change [Prompt.Choice] options' color? 
Is it possible to change the options' color? I need to change some special options' color.

Comment: Which channel you are using now? If you are using webchat, you can try to write custom css style to override the default style.

Comment: I use teams @FeiHan

Comment: In teams, might not support us to customize it.

Comment: I see.. Thanks .. do you know how to  accept text in Prompt.Choice that is not in list of options?   
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51758085/how-to-accept-text-in-prompt-choice-that-is-not-in-list-of-options-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment90481682_51758085

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The styling of the various channels is set by the channel itself, with the exception of webchat, which can be altered using CSS. You can see what various features looks like in the channels by using the [Channel Inspector Tool](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/channel-inspector/channels/Skype/).